# Independent conditions of unitary matrix, $U U^{\dagger}=1$ and $U^{\dagger}U = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, constraints, unitary-matrices

I am trying to show that, for a simple 2x2 complex matrix
\begin{equation}
U = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
there will be only 4 real constraints for $U$ to be unitary. I will denote the conjugate transpose by $\dagger$, for example the complex transpose of a matrix $A$ is $A^{\dagger}$. I will also use $*$ to denote complex conjugation of a complex number, for example $a^{*}$ is the complex conjugate of complex number $a$. I first carry out the calculation
\begin{equation}
UU^{\dagger}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
a^{*} & c^{*} \\ b^{*} & d^{*}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
|a|^{2}+|b|^{2} & a c^{*} + b d^{*} \\ a^{*}c+b^{*}d & |c|^{2} + |d|^{2}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
which leads to the constraints
\begin{align}
& |a|^{2}+|b|^{2} = 1 \\
& a c^{*} + b d^{*} = 0 \\
& a^{*}c+b^{*}d = 0 \\
& |c|^{2} + |d|^{2} = 1.
\end{align}
The second and third are same, and each of them gives 2 real constraints. The first and the fourth both give 1 real constraint. So in total the above four equations give 4 real constraints.

I know that $UU^{\dagger} = U^{\dagger}U$ and so $U^{\dagger}U=1$ should give no more constraints. But still I calculate it as
\begin{equation}
U^{\dagger}U= \begin{bmatrix}
a^{*} & c^{*} \\ b^{*} & d^{*}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
|a|^{2}+|c|^{2} & a^{*} b + c^{*} d \\ ab^{*}+c d^{*} & |b|^{2} + |d|^{2}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
which leads to the constraints
\begin{align}
& |a|^{2}+|c|^{2} = 1 \\
&  a^{*} b + c^{*} d = 0 \\
& ab^{*}+c d^{*} = 0 \\
&|b|^{2} + |d|^{2} = 1.
\end{align}
Now it seems to me that it is not obvious why the constraints obtained from $U^{\dagger}U = 1$ are independent of those obtained from $U U^{\dagger}=1$. However, we know that $U U^{\dagger}=1$ should imply $U^{\dagger}U = 1$. Could anyone give me some suggestions? I think I just miss some simple points, but currently haven't figured out the key points. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does † mean transpose? And what does a∗ refer to? Please clarify your notations.

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda $\dagger$ is common notation for the conjugate transponse and ${a}^*$ is common notation for the conjugate of the complex number $a$.

Comment: Yeah, these are physicist notations

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda sorry for the notation issue, by $\dagger$ I mean conjugate transpose and $*$ means complex conjugation of a complex number. I have edited the post and so hopefully this will clarify.

Comment: @Gae.S. thanks for helping me clarify

Comment: @LL3.14 yeah I am in physics.

Answer (score 1):

Since $ac^\ast=-bd^\ast$, $|a|^2|c|^2=|b|^2|d|^2$, i.e. $|a|^2-|a|^2|d|^2=|d|^2-|a|^2|d|^2$, whence $|a|=|d|$. But $|b|^2-|c|^2=|d|^2-|a|^2=0$, so$$ab^\ast=-bd^\ast\cdot(b/c)^\ast=-|b|^2(d/c)^\ast=-|c|^2(d/c)^\ast=-cd^\ast.$$